# How to write unit test for nested JavaScript methods using Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

Here is my calculator.js file and it has nested methods. How can I write a unit test for the add, sub, mul and div methods using Jest?

```
function Calculator() {
    var self = this;
    
    self.add = function (a, b) {
        return a+b;
    }
    
    self.sub = function(a, b) {
        return a-b;
    }
    
    self.mul = function(a, b) {
        return a*b;
    }

    self.div = function(a, b) {
        return a/b;
    }               
}
```

Comment: You can't. Those functions aren't exposed anywhere. Also `var self = this;` isn't used.

Comment: @jonrsharpe updated code block. 
How to expose this file and make it testable?

Comment: That's no longer JavaScript, `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'`. Why have you written this code - how were you _intending_ to use it? That's what your tests should reflect, and you don't have to wait until you have an implementation to start writing them (read up on TDD).

Comment: Any reason you're not using a class?

Comment: @jonrsharpe updated code syntax.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum This is an existing code snippet.

Comment: _Is_ it an existing code snippet? You didn't seem to know what code you actually had. This is something that would at least be testable, so again: how were you intending to use it? Have you tried writing a test for (or actually using) any of those methods? What happened?